Refresh Knowledgebase in Measure and Probability Theory
Currently i am searching for a book, for refresh my knowledgebase in Measure Theory and Probability Theory. Are they books "Measure Theory, Probality, and Stochastic Processes" from Jean-Francois Le Gall and "Probability Essentials" from Jacod Protter recommendable for self-study? I want to hear your opinions about this books. They are other books to prefer for self-study by Measure Theory and Probability Theory?

I highly recommend Measure Theory 2nd edition by Donald Cohn.
You can go through Chapters 1 to 5 (Measures, Functions and Integrals, Convergence, Signed and Complex Measures, and Product Measures, respectively) and then move on directly to Chapter 10 which is an introduction to measure-theoretic probability. It covers all the fundamentals of probability theory you need to know (laws of large numbers, convergence in distribution, central limit theorem, conditional distributions, martingales, Brownian motions, and so forth) before digging into more advanced topics from books such as Billingsley's Probability and Measure (which is golden and classic).
PS: You can read Chapter 6 (Differentiation) before Chapter 10 if you want, but it's not really necessary.
The presentation is thorough and super clear. The proofs are detailed yet not wordy. I honestly think it might be the best option for self-study measure theory with an introduction to probability.
